# Change specific value in array and array is empty

Tags: javascript

I create new array and add to her specific values. I add in first index and first index has value, but if I add in second or more index, last indexes are empty and I don't know why. Here my code.

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.input')];

let timeout = null;

inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    let inputValue = Number(input.value);

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (index !== 1) {
        let arr = [];

        if (index === 0) {
          arr[0] = inputValue;
        } else if (index === 2) {
          arr[1] = inputValue;
        } else if (index === 3) {
          arr[2] = inputValue;
        } else if (index === 4) {
          arr[3] = inputValue;
        }

        console.log(arr);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: `arr` needs to be a global variable.

Comment: it is working, thanks dude I forgot about global variable 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of the "push" array function. Example:

```
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.input')];

let timeout = null;
let arr = [];

inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    let inputValue = Number(input.value);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        arr.push(inputValue);
        console.log(arr);      
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```